# JPA update with a join

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I use spring-jpa with hibernate implementation.
I use mariadb
I try to do an update with a join.

My object structure

```
@Entity
public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long roomId;

    @ManyToOne  
    @JoinColumn(name = "appartment_id")
    private Appartment appartment;
}

@Entity
public class Appartment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long appartmentId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="appartment_id")
    private Set<Room> roomList;
}
```

My sql query

```
update  Room r1 set r1.available = :availability
    where  r1.roomId in (
        SELECT  r2.roomId
            from  Room r2
            JOIN  r2.appartment a1
            WHERE  a1.appartmentId = :appartmentId
```

tried also

```
update  Room r1 set r1.available = :availability
    where  exists 
      ( SELECT  r2
            from  Room r2
            JOIN  r2.appartment a1
            where  a1.appartmentId= :appartmentId 
      )
```

I get this error

java.sql.SQLException: Table 'room' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Seem like update and join with mysql seem impossible?

Answer (score 3):

Everytime you get the **unexpected token** exception, look for syntax errors.

In your case the update query should look like this:

```
UPDATE Room r1
SET r1.available = :availability
WHERE r1.roomId in
( SELECT r2.roomId FROM Room r2 JOIN r2.appartment a1 WHERE a1.appartmentId = :appartmentId )
```

**EDIT (follow-up issue):**

[Here you may find some help for your follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

The accepted answer features a MySQL example on how to perform an update with a JOIN. I'm quite sure that's what you're after. Now it would look something like this:

```
UPDATE Room r1 JOIN r1.appartment a1
SET r1.available = :availability
WHERE a1.appartmentId = :appartmentId
```

try it with your dialect but if it doesn't work, the following one should do the trick:

```
UPDATE Room r1 SET r1.available = :availability WHERE r1.appartment.appartmentId = :appartmentId
```

Comment: You may also encounter this exception when dealing with some DB specific functions which may not be known to the dialect you're using. That's just a sidenote.

Answer (score 0):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` has poor performance characteristics.  Since you are looking at an `UPDATE`, I recommend a multi-table `UPDATE`.  Or `EXISTS` is good -- but *not* that `EXISTS`.  You have not tied the two instances of `Room` together; the `UPDATE` will change *all* or *none* of the rows!

Since you have not explained what the query is supposed to do, I cannot advise you on how to do it.